# Print data from json response to AS3 label

Tags: json, actionscript-3

This is the json response i'm getting from API, I used.

```
 trace(loader.data);
```

---

```
 httpStatusHandler:200
 {"status":"success","data":  
 [{"cab_id":"101","rating_up":"4","rating_down":"4"}],"errors":""}
```

I need to decode it and print in AS3 .Can anyone show mew how to do so.
  Tried this,

---

```
var myData:Object = JSON.decode(loader.data);

trace(myData[1]);
trace(myData->rating_up);
trace(myData.toString());  
none working!!! Any help?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try something like

```
trace(myData.data[0].cab_id);
trace(myData.data[0].rating_up);
trace(myData.data[0].rating_down);
```